# Java-callable n-Sampler for Spark Dataset

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I'm migrating code from Python to Java and want to build an n-Sampler for `Dataset<Row>`. It's been a bit frustrating, I ended up cheating and making a very inefficient Scala function for it based off other posts. I then run the function from my Java code, but even that hasn't worked

N-Sample behaviour:
- Select N-rows randomly from dataset
- No repetitions (no replacement)

Current Solution (broken)

```
import scala.util.Random

object ScalaFunctions {
  def nSample(df : org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row], n : Int) : org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = {
    //inefficient! Shuffles entire dataframe
    val output = Random.shuffle(df).take(n)
    return output.asInstanceOf[org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]]
  }
}
```

Error Message

```
Error:(6, 25) inferred type arguments [org.apache.spark.sql.Row,org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset] do not conform to method shuffle's type parameter bounds [T,CC[X] <: TraversableOnce[X]]
    val output = Random.shuffle(df).take(n)
Error:(6, 33) type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
 required: CC[T]
    val output = Random.shuffle(df).take(n)
```

I'm new to Java and Scala, so even though I understand the shuffle function doesn't seem to like Datasets, I have no idea how to fix it.
- Virtual beer if you have a solution that doesn't involve shuffling the entire dataframe (for me, this could be like 4M rows) for a small n sample (250)

Comment: Apart from possibly not getting exactly the number of samples you want, is there some reason you can't just use `Dataset.sample()`?

Comment: The exact number is quite important in my case, as I'm trying to benchmark an algorithm from a paper that used an exact sample size.